# Rails: how to model a Vehicle and all of its types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, types, model, has-one

I have a Vehicle model:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
validates_presence_of :num_of_wheels
validates_presence_of :make
validates_presence_of :model
end
```

From this class, I'd like to have a scaleable number of Vehicle types such as "Passenger Car", "Motorcycle", "Truck", each with it's own unique mandatory attributes. For example, PassengerCar might require the number of doors, while that's not applicable to the Motorcycle type. At the same time, both motorcycles and passenger_cars should require/inherit the mandatory attributes of Vehicle, when they're created.

The key here is that I can't really anticipate the number of different types of Vehicles that may be invented or that I need to store. So, I need a scaleable way to add new Vehicle types. Also, in terms of the UI and view, it would be nice to be able to create a new Vehicle type, if my type isn't available from a drop-down menu, for example, and have the db populate the Vehicle type and have that reflected back into the UI.

What would be the best way of modeling this relationship with Rails? I'm thinking of using the has_one :through relationship, but I'm not sure that's the best way. For example, the Vehicle will be assigned to an Operator. And a person can be operating only one Vehicle at a time...so, I could say:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :motorcycle, :through => :vehicle_type
has_one :passenger_car, :through => :vehicle_type
has_many :vehicle_types
validates_presence_of :num_of_wheels
validates_presence_of :make
validates_presence_of :model
end

class VehicleType < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :vehicle
belongs_to :passenger_car
belongs_to :motorcycle
end

class PassengerCar < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :vehicle_type
validates_presence_of :doors
end

class Motorcycle < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :vehicle_type
validates_presence_of :saddlebags
end
```

However, it seems unwieldy to have to add every possible type to the Vehicle model and since the Operator can only drive one Vehicle at at a time, it seems redundant to put every other type of vehicle in the :has_one statement of the Vehicle model.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You probably want to consider reading up on the single table inheritance mechanism. There's a good article describing it here: http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to set this relationship up using Rails' [single table inheritance mechanism](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html) and either additional table columns (faster) or a serialized hash (won't require a new migration if you want to add new properties) for the specifics of each model. Here's the idea:

Add a `type` column to the migration that's creating your `vehicles` table to tip Rails off that you would like to use single table inheritance:

```
def change
  create_table :vehicles do |t|
    t.string :type

    # if using serialization
    t.text :parameters

    # if using custom fields
    t.integer :saddlebags
    t.integer :doors

    # ...
  end
end
```

You'll be using Vehicle as the base class, and from here on out your specific vehicles will be inheriting its base properties:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :num_of_wheels, :make, :model

  # if using serialization
  serialize :parameters, Hash

  # ...
end

class PassengerCar < Vehicle
end

class Motorcycle < Vehicle
end

# etc..
```

Now, when an `Operator` is assigned to a vehicle, Rails will automagically restore the appropriate class:

```
# models/Operator.rb
class Operator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :vehicle
end

# in controller action
op = Operator.new
op.vehicle = Motorcycle.new
op.vehicle.save
op.save
# op will now be assigned to a +Motorcycle+ the next time it's loaded
```

Validations will work as you describe them if you're using additional columns in your table. If you opt to serialize them into `parameters`, however, your best bet might be to produce [custom validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations) for each model's `parameters` hash.

Comment: this is perfect! Thanks for the complete thought! Since I don't anticipate having too many unique attributes, I think just adding separate table columns will suffice for me. Plus, I cringe a little when serializing data in the DB.